# using post__in allow duplicate post id

Tags: query-posts, query

I have an array of ids in a specific order. I use `post__in` in my query to get posts from this array. I have some duplicate post IDs that I need to show twice in the page but the query seems to ignore them.
Let's say the array is as follows

```
array values  = 1,2,3,4,2,5
```

When I pass this array to `post__in`, it doesn't take value `'2'` twice as i specified in the array. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you using this with `WP_Query`?

Comment: Kaiser: i am using query_posts and post__in is in my $args

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

## The situation

An array like `array( 1,2,3,4,2,5 )` will be read like the following:

```
Array(
     0 => 1
    ,1 => 2
    ,2 => 3
    ,3 => 4
    ,4 => 2
    ,5 => 5
) [length = 6 ]
```

which seems ok. But when you look at the `WP_Query` object, you'll see the following part added to the query string:

```
" AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ($post__in)"
```

This means that each post will be fetched once.

## Conclusion

So unless you don't modify the query to include the post multiple times, you'll be left with only an option to do this on runtime.

## Runtime configuration possibilities and x-raying the internals

Every basic loop looks like this:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts )
    {
        the_post();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now the `global $post` refers to what gets setup via `the_post()`. It basically is a wrapper for `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->the_post();`. And when you take a look at the `WP_Query::the_post()` method, you'll find quite interesting things:

```
function the_post() {
    global $post;
    $this->in_the_loop = true;

    if ( $this->current_post == -1 ) // loop has just started
        do_action_ref_array('loop_start', array(&$this));

    $post = $this->next_post();
    setup_postdata($post);
}
```

There you see `$this->next_post();` called. And this one looks from the inside like the following:

```
function next_post() {

    $this->current_post++;

    $this->post = $this->posts[$this->current_post];
    return $this->post;
}
```

## Solution

So you see that the main thing the loop relies on, is the `current_post` counter. This one is as well accessible from the front end/a template. Simply use

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post
```

to "jump" between posts. So if you need to repeat a post after post X, then just check against it, switch for one round and then skip back.

Comment: kaiser, great solution. but the array i am giving comes from a wpdb that queries the database for certain posts. So i don't always know when there will be a repeating ID.

Comment: @KT. That's no problem. Just use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts` and use basic Math functions to calculate your way through it (how many steps do I have to jump back-/forward?).

Comment: im not quite sure i understand what you mean. please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: @KT. Just use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts` to get the maximum limit. Then use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post` with math operators like `++` or `--` to switch forward or backward inside the `$wp_query` object get the desired posts. You can as well use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->next_post()` and similar to switch your posts around. Align that with your array and you're fine.

Comment: @KT. If this is too much for you, then you might consider looking for a solution on StackOverflow that lets you sort an array like `$wp_query` posts object by the numerical keys of another array. This would work as well.

Comment: I tried doing this and it does work. my only problem is the pagination. My template needs to display only 16 posts_per_page as it is in a 4x4 grid design. Inserting the posts while in the loop breaks the design because even when already 16 posts have been shown, the query does not know this and does not move to the next page. Any thoughts?

Comment: @KT. This is a completely different question. If the current question was solved, please mark it as such and ask a new one about pagination.

Comment: This answer seems very thoughtful, but I feel like the last bit with the implementation is hard to understand. It seems like the goal is to loop through an array of IDs and include any duplicates. So, is fooling the current post counter the only way to do that? And if so, how would we write that?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop your ids and call `get_post` and `setup_postdata` :

```
global $post;
foreach ($ids as $id) :
    $post = get_post($id);
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
endforeach;
```